# Video playback during changing device orientation

Tags: android, video, webview

I have `Webview` which can play video in fullscreen.
I need to have ability of continious playback when change orientation.
And most important - I need this ability without `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"`

Comment: You won't get the seamless playback without using `android:configChanges`. May I ask why you cannot use this?

Comment: Because the same application is run in two modes: for phone and for the tablet.
Cordova is used for the phone mode and native android - for tablet.
In phone mode we can use android:onfigchanges, in tablet mode - no.

Answer (score 0):

When you change orientation the activity is killed and a new activity is created on the new orieentation. So you have to saveInstanceState of your player components, and restore them with the new orientation.Use :

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: I know about this but I don't realize how to implement this on HTML5 Video Surface